# How to send json object to android in codeigniter?

Tags: json, codeigniter

I am new in codeigniter. I want to send json object to android. I have done this in my controller:

```
function index()
 {
    $data=array('a'=>1,'b'=>2,'c'=>3);
    $suzan=json_encode($data);
    print_r($suzan);
    $decode=json_decode($suzan);
    print_r($decode);
    exit();
 }
```

I am getting this as output in browser:

```
    {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}stdClass Object ( [a] => 1 [b] => 2 [c] => 3 )
```

Here stdClass Object came out of nowhere. I want to get json data in json object. How can i do that? And am I in track for sending these data to android. I mean when android hits this URL will it get data?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
function index()
{
$data['jsonobject'] = array('a'=>1,'b'=>2,'c'=>3);
exit(json_encode($data));
}
```

Comment: {"jsonobject":{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}}

Comment: exit(json_encode(array("jsonobject" => array('a'=>1,'b'=>2,'c'=>3))) - like this?

Comment: function index()
{
$data['jsonobject']=array('a'=>1,'b'=>2,'c'=>3);
exit(json_encode($data));
}

Comment: use this may be it will help you

Answer (score 1):

For your answer, do `$data['jsonobject'] = array('a'=>1,'b'=>2,'c'=>3)`
Then `print_r(json_encode($data));`